# Can I make an OData endpoint return all object properties, including properties from descending classes

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-odata

My Odata endpoint is returning a set of JSON objects. The method on the controller is returning IQueryable< MyBaseClass >

The objects are of different types, but all inherit from the same MyBaseClass.

When I query the endpoint the result only includes the properties of the base class, but I would like the json objects to contain all the properties from decending classes too. Is this possible?

I'm using .Net 6 and OData v4

( In an older version of the code using an older version of OData, the endpoint does return all the properties )

I can create some example code it is unclear what I mean.

---

Ok, here is my simplified example:

Controller, with data:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace ODataTest.Controllers {
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/")]
    public class AnimalsController : ODataController {
        static List<Animal> data = new List<Animal>() {
            new Dog(){Id=1, Name="Pluto", Legs=4},
            new Fish(){Id=2, Name="Nemo", Fins=8}
        };
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Animal> Get() {
            return data.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Program:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy());

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The response to "/?$select=name" is ( just to test OData query works) :

```
[{"Name":"Pluto"},{"Name":"Nemo"}]
```

The response to "/" is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Pluto"},{"id":2,"name":"Nemo"}]
```

The response I would to "/" like is is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Pluto", "legs": 4},{"id":2,"name":"Nemo", "fins":8}]
```

---

After looking more carfully at it I realised I was not adding a full Odata endpoint. When I added

options.AddRouteComponents("/odata", getEdmModel());

It worked as I wanted. The output is now:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:7042/odata/$metadata#Animals","value":[{"@odata.type":"#ODataTest.Dog","Id":1,"Name":"Pluto","Legs":4},{"@odata.type":"#ODataTest.Fish","Id":2,"Name":"Nemo","Fins":8}]}
```

Comment: Yes, The result is what you have for the real instance(s). If it doesn't work, please create the sample and share the link for us to dig more.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll be back with a sample

Comment: You should also post the relevant sections from the $metadata. This might be something simple as using the _type `cast`_ to access the derived type definition.